# R and quantreg : Unbalanced residuals

Tags: r, regression, quantreg

I'm trying to use the `quantreg` package to fit an exponential curve.

Here is a reproductible example. IRL I have much more complex data with outliers, that's why I prefer not using `nls` which is not robust to outliers.

```
library(quantreg)
library(ggplot2)

x = 1:100
set.seed(42)
y = 500*exp(-0.02*x) +rnorm(100, 0, 5 )
df = data.frame(cbind(x,y))
plot(df)

formula =  y ~ k * exp(b*x) 
qr_exp = nlrq(formula,
                   data = df,
                   start = list(k = 600, b = -0.01),
                   tau = .50,
                   nlrq.control(maxiter=1000))
summary(qr_exp)
sum(qr_exp$m$resid())
[1] -26.52373
```

I expected to have `sum(qr_exp$m$resid())` around 0 since  `tau = 0.5`but the value is negative which means the model tend to overestimate the real values.

As you can see I have sum of the residual is closer to 0 with `tau= 0.47`

```
formula =  y ~ k * exp(b*x) 
qr_exp = nlrq(formula,
              data = df,
              start = list(k = 600, b = -0.01),
              tau = .47,
              nlrq.control(maxiter=1000))
summary(qr_exp)
sum(qr_exp$m$resid())
[1] -4.467781
```

I don't really understand why.

Is it because there could be [an infinite number of solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations#Other_properties) and so no guarantee of having as much negative residual than positive residual?

If yes what is the best solution if this is very important for me to:

- minimise Least absolute deviation  and not least square deviation (not robust with outliers)
- have balanced residual?

Could it make sense to add a small portion of L2 penalty to have something balanced ? *(see [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss))*

Comment: you are using quantile regression instead of least square, are you aware of this? (`nls` or `optim` + objective function to build should be enough for your problem)

Comment: As alluded to above, I'm not sure why you expect the residuals to be symmetric around an estimate of the median. There should be the same _number_ of observations above and below the median, but their magnitudes may be quite different.

Comment: @joran tha'ts not true. Quantile regression = Least Absolute Deviation when tau=0.5 and we don't want half of the record above but we want to mimimise the sum of the absolute deviation.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel This is just a basic reproductive example. This is really important for me to not being impacted by outlier and to minimise the LAD.  That's why `nls` doesn't fit here.

Comment: this question seems more suitable for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).  Also, it would be good to use `set.seed()` so your example is reproducible ...

Comment: I'm certainly no quantile regression expert, I just mean to say that based on what I _do_ know I don't share your intuition/expectation that the residuals ought to be symmetrically distributed around the conditional median in this case.